# Is it possible to buy a Navigo Découverte travel card at Orly airport late at night?

Tags: public-transport, paris, opening-hours, ory

Is it  possible to buy a [Navigo Découverte](http://parisbytrain.com/paris-train-metro-week-pass-navigo-decouverte/) at Orly airport?

My arrival is on Wednesday, May 7th at 22:50. I would like to buy Navigo for zones 1-5 to cover journeys from and to the airport.

Is the office at Orly airport open at that time?

Is the card price the same for adults as for students?

Comment: If Orly and Versailles are as far out as you'll go, zones 1–4 are enough. Note that the weekly pass runs from Monday to Sunday, not an arbitrary 7-day period.

Answer (score 4):

You can buy it from Orlybus at the airport, which runs from [6am until 11.30pm](http://en.parisinfo.com/transport/73374/Orlybus).  You can use the ND on the Orly bus service as well.

[Prices depend on zones / length of time, but cost the same for everyone.](http://parisbytrain.com/carte-orange-navigo-decouverte-prices/)